# how to set file and dir permissions on docker when developing

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-volume

I'm developing a symfony application with docker.
I' sharing a host volume which it's supposed to contain my project that should be run with apache.

```
docker run -d -ti --name web -p 80:80 -v /Users/Matteo/Documents/em3:/var/www/html/applications  ubuntu /bin/bash
```

As a base image I've used ubuntu, on which I've installed apache and PHP7. Everything works, but when I enter into my docker:

```
docker exec -it web /bin/bash

root@85a23559d01b:/var/www/html/applications/auth# app/console cache:clear --env=dev


  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
  Failed to remove directory "/var/www/html/applications/auth/app/cache/de~/jms_serializer": .
```

This is maybe because the dir permissions?:

```
root@85a23559d01b:/var/www/html/applications/auth/app# ls -al | grep cache

drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 staff   374 Oct 30 21:50 cache
```

`chmod` does no change anything though:

```
root@85a23559d01b:/var/www/html/applications/auth/app# chmod g+w cache

root@85a23559d01b:/var/www/html/applications/auth/app# ls -al | grep cache
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 staff   374 Oct 30 21:50 cache
```

I guess I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented in [symfony issue 2600](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2600#issuecomment-3031959)

> you can "easily" reproduce this if you use a Linux VirtualBox on a Windows host.

[And that might be the case here, using `boot2docker` from [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/), instead of [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) and its Hyper-V]

> `cache:clear` is never able to remove `app/cache/dev_old` - but that may be an issue with the shared folder system provided by VirtualBox (read about similar issues on their forums).
>
> You have to upgrade [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

The [OP Bertuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192829/bertuz) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334251/how-to-set-file-and-dir-permissions-on-docker-when-developing/40334495?noredirect=1#comment67937773_40334495) to "[Changing boot2docker to use NFS for local mounts in OS X](https://quip.com/EDYLAAfuup5M)" and its [file-nfs-mount-boot2docker-sh](https://gist.github.com/sirkkalap/40261ed82386ad8a6409#file-nfs-mount-boot2docker-sh) gist (and a [more recent one](https://gist.github.com/haggen/f84f55e3ed2c9c930335)).

Comment: I guess the best way would be using NFS for my docker-machine then. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes I do: it seems to make the deletion possible

Comment: @Bertuz OK: I have included that reference in the answer for more visibility.